# How to create modules in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, module

I can't create modules in yii.I have a parent directory with name `jobsite_orginal`,it can run by these url `localhost/yii/jobsite_orginal/`.

I have created a folder name `modules` in protected folder of `jobsite_orginal` directory. After that i have created the folder name `supplier`. Supplier folder includes the controller,views and components folders and also the file SupplierModule.php.

I had edited the main file in config folder. After that i run the project with localhost/yii/jobsite_orginal/supplier/site/register
(register is the action in the conroller site ie in the  supplier module),but i dont get.Anybody help me?

My SupplierModule.php

```
<?php
class SupplierModule extends CWebModule
{
public $defaultController = 'Site';
}
 ?>
```

My config/main.php

```
    'modules'=>array(
      'supplier'=>array()
),
```

Comment: You do everything right, maybe this page doesn't work because site is in some subdirectory and routing doesn't work. You also can try to create module with gii.

Comment: i am trying for module without gii.Any mistake in these url  localhost/yii/jobsite_orginal/supplier/site/register ?

Comment: Yes, pages other in application (not modules) works?

Comment: I want to get register action in the module supplier..can you give me the correct url?

Comment: It depends on your application settings and web-server settings, i may suppose if you say wheather other site pages work

Comment: I cant understand..any need of model folder in the supplier folder?

Comment: Do you have this settings in your config 'urlManager' => array( 'urlFormat' => CUrlManager::PATH_FORMAT, 'showScriptName' => false... ?

Comment: Path format doesn't work in subdirectory i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove PATH_FORMAT from urlManager settings and showScriptName = false then try this url

```
localhost/yii/jobsite_orginal/index.php?r=supplier/site/register
```

Comment: ok,I got that page,but i have a doubt any need of add the folder 'model'  in module->supplier folder?

Comment: There is no need to add model folder in module. Please mark my answer as right.

Comment: but, i dont get with out module.. validation error,my supplier module have another model ie another tables not same as parent project,but same database.